# Setting up Android Webiew for Razorpay checkout

Tags: android, android-webview, razorpay

I want to integrate Razorpay payment gateway in Android via Webview.

Following steps like provided in [here](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/ios-integration/webapp/)!

```
public class RazorPayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_razor_pay);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.activity_razor_pay_web_view);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        PaymentInterface paymentInterface = new PaymentInterface();

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(paymentInterface, "PaymentInterface");
String html = "<html><script> var options = {callback_url: my_url',redirect: true}</script></html>";
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("base_url",html , "text/html", "utf-8", null);

}

 class PaymentInterface{
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void success(String data){
            Log.i("RAZORPAY_LOG","success: "+data);
        }
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void error(String data){
            Log.i("RAZORPAY_LOG","error: "+data);
        }
    }
```

I also have a callback URL which as given is to be passed to handle the incoming POST requests.

```
   var options = {
      callback_url: 'https://your-server/callback_url',
      redirect: true
    }
```

I am not able to get control back into the app from webview after payment checkout is done via Razorpay URL sent as base_url.

Can anyone please help me with the missing part in this whole process?

Comment: are you able to resolve this issue? I am also stcuk here in same situation.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure your JS to Native Bridge works correctly by calling the JavascriptInterface objects from JS/WebView. [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))
2. Try debugging the WebView, check JS console for possible error outputs. [WebView debugging info](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)